# How can I increase the size of Terraria's pixels or UI?

Tags: terraria

Is there a way to increase the scale in Terraria? I want to play the game at full 1080p HD but the item bar is way too small.

Comment: I think there might be mods for this but I am not sure.  I will have to check.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could find something to help me.

Comment: I believe this forum thread may help you http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/zoom-in-zoom-out.76733/

Comment: Thx for the help mate , i`ll try that and tell you if it works

Comment: Well thx again for the help, it is working

Comment: What did you find? The forum thread is a dead link now.

Answer (score 1):

There might be mods for it, but in normal Terraria, there is no way to increase the size of the item bar, pixels or UI without hacking.